# which process in windows is user specific?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, windows-services

i wanted to know which process in Windows is user specific, i mean it get created for each user login. i tried explorer.exe but when u switch user and log into new account then it shows old login name in my code. basically i need to just log which user logging when in app.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking; are you just trying to figure out the name of the current user account?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Your application isn't going to continue running when a user logs out *anyway*.

Comment: I am running a service which checks and logs username of currently logged in. i used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777548/how-do-i-determine-the-owner-of-a-process-in-c to get username from service but facing problem which i mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed the tag indicating you created a Windows Service. That's a very different type of animal than a regular application, and the advice you receive for one is not necessarily transferable to the other.

Specifically, I notice that you've tagged this question `windows-7`. If you're trying to run this service under Windows 7, you need to understand a few things about how the model for Windows Services was substantially altered starting with Windows Vista. Specifically, [they now run in an isolated session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa480152.aspx#appcomp_topic12) and are prohibited from interacting directly with the user. 
Also see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516200/how-can-a-windows-service-start-a-process-when-a-timer-event-is-raised/4516515#4516515) for a better explanation.

The fundamental point is that, **from the perspective of a Windows Service, there is no such concept as the currently logged-on user**. A Windows Service runs in its own isolated session and is not affiliated with any particular user. That's why the [code you found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777548/how-do-i-determine-the-owner-of-a-process-in-c) to determine the user associated with a particular process is not working as you expect for a Windows Service. A standard user doesn't own the process running the service. (And replacing your service with an application is also not a viable option, given how I understand your requirements. [As I explain here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813138/need-suggestion-on-replacing-windows-service-by-invisible-winform-application/4813184#4813184), user-mode applications are started when a particular user logs on and will be closed whenever that user logs off.)

Another problem is that more than one user can be logged in *simultaneously* to a single workstation. Windows is a thoroughly multi-user operating system, so the best that you can hope for is to enumerate *all* of the currently logged in users. The [`NetWkstaUserEnum` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370669.aspx) will get you that list, but note that it includes all types of logons, including interactive users, services, and batch logons. To call this function from C#, you will need to P/Invoke—you can find information about that over on [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/NetWkstaUserEnum.html).

Answer (score 2):

If all you need to know is which user(s) are using your app, can you just check `Environment.UserName` when you start your app?