# How to delay Topshelf service stopping during OS shutdown

Tags: c#, windows-services, topshelf

We have a windows service created with Topshelf (4.0.1). Is there any way how to delay it's stopping during operating system shutdown?

I know it's pretty problematic desire so an explanation: Let's say that we have win service what needs some additional time during shutdown (some tasks have to be completed correctly and *now we have no way how to perform it faster*).

It's possible to delay standard service stop (performed e.g. by Powershell `Stop-Service` cmdlet or so...) by calling `RequestAdditionalTime()` in the service `OnStop()`. It all works well when stopping the service in such "standard" way... But `RequestAdditionalTime()` cannot be used during system shutdown (i.e. windows service `OnShutdown()`). Because of that I've implemented this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25753087/388834) approvach in classical windows service and 3:20 delay was achieved by that (that's what we need).

*But mentioned SO answer solution (hack, better to say) doesn't work with Topshelf.*

Is there any way how to do it with Topshelf?

Comment: When a power cut hits, you don't get any time to complete things correctly. Think of system shutdown as a power cut that you get a little warning for. If you need to do more work, arrange for it to happen well *before* the power cut hits. It may be painful but re-architecting your system to not need to do so much work during system shutdown is the better long term approach.

Comment: E.g. SQL Server has a transaction log where everything it *will do* when a transaction is completed is recorded. During the next *startup*, it uses that log to determine which transaction had been completed and to ensure their effects take place, and similarly to roll back any transactions that didn't complete. In this way, it's able to shut down fast at the expense of more work during startup - but it has to be this way to be *resilient* to sudden shutdowns (including, as mentioned, power cuts)

Comment: In ideal world where everything could be done in transaction, it is really not problem. Imagine you sending e-mail, you want to minimize cases there you send duplicate just because you would not be able to write information that you already finished sending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to register a custom `EnvironmentBuilder` (using extension method `UseEnvironmentBuilder` on a `HostConfigurator` instance) that returns a customized implementation of the `HostEnvironment` interface. Custom implementation of the `HostEnvironment.CreateServiceHost` method can return any implementation of `Host` you need (e.g. a `Host` that [`Run()`s](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/blob/master/src/Topshelf/Runtime/Windows/WindowsServiceHost.cs#L79) your `ServiceBase`).

You can reuse implementation of other `HostEnvironment` / `Host` methods by forwarding calls to `WindowsHostEnvironment` and `WindowsServiceHost` classes, respectively. `WindowsHostEnvironment` instance can be simply created in your custom `EnvironmentBuilder` constructor (and passed into custom `HostEnvironment`).

Comment: @zbynour I'm trying to create similar thing in Topshelf. Could You please share Your code?

Comment: @Misiu It should be enough to follow the answer itself. What particular issue are you interested about?

Comment: @zbynour I don't know how to use `UseEnvironmentBuilder` and `ServicePreshutdownBase` from Your question. If I use `UseEnvironmentBuilder` I must pass `EnvironmentBuilderFactory` and right here I don't know how to combine those two

Comment: @Misiu Take a look at that one: https://gist.github.com/zbynourcz/575110dfd65becd3078da6da8353df85 `FooHostEnvironment.CreateServiceHost()` meth is crucial since you return `Host` instance there. As a `Host` instance you can use your own implementation inheriting `Topshelf.Runtime.Windows.WindowsServiceHost` (what implements `ServiceBase`). Does it help?