# SetWindowsHookEx vs. SetWinHookEventEx

Tags: c#, .net, windows, api

What are the main differences (how it works/dependencies/purpose/minimal requirements) between SetWindowsHookEx and SetWinEventHook ?

I'm interested in intercepting events related to running windows applications from a Windows service using C#/.Net.

Comment: Down-voter please explain. This is a good question.

Answer (score 9):

`SetWindowsHookEx` sets low-level hooks which can intercept and re-write several system-wide events and messages (like capturing and re-writing keyboard input).

`SetWinEventHook` allows you to listen to Window events without having a window. It's higher level and less intrusive to the system.

Neither of this is required for *running* other applications from a service. Look at `System.Diagnostics.Process` (built into .Net) or `RunProcess` on NuGet

Answer (score 3):

> If i understand you correctly, you want to use a service that you
>   created to intercept the messages that are flowing between the OS and
>   running Windows applications.

If that is the case your best choice is [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this will create a system level hook which you will have to filter pass on to other appliations. You should note that this requires you to also build c++ .dll file from which you would call the SetWindowsHookEx function. **Be very careful when coding because an error could lock up the entire system** and you will need a restart to get things back to normal.

Comment: Another constraint is that since Vista it's not possible to directly set a global hook from a Windows service as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815424/global-keyboard-hook-from-windows-service) and a solution is to spawn a child process to do that instead.