# Global Key Hook in ASP.Net Core using C#/.Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, keyboard-hook, asp.net-core-2.2

**Environment**

- ASP.NET Core Application with Kestrel hosted as Windows Service using .Net Core 2.2
- Angualar Application which is delivered through the ASP.NET application
- Web API for communicating between the ASP.NET and Angular application
- Everything is running on one Windows PC. The Angular application will always be only available on localhost

**Use Case**

A user makes a screenshot of a WPF application also running on the same PC using the *print key*. The ASP.NET application needs now a trigger, that a screenshot was made so it can be send to the angular application.

**Solution approach**

I thought that I would just listen with a global hook for the print key and then get the image from the clipboard. I've tried using the [low level Windows API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application) and different Nuget packages (for example [this one](https://github.com/jnm2/LowLevelHooking)). Either nothing happened or the application froze.

**Question**

Is there a way listening globally for the key press of the *print key* in .Net Core 2.2 application or is there another approach I can listen for new screenshots made by the user?

Comment: This will be because your service is isolated from the user and is going to end up  hooking it *own* desktop, See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815424/global-keyboard-hook-from-windows-service

Comment: Why would you even consider such a hilarious setup instead of just starting an WPF/Windows Form application that runs minimized and does the same w/o angular and just a WebAPI in the background? Even Electron + Angular or something else would make far more sense, than to abuse an ASP.NET Application for that

Comment: I know it sounds stupid, but this setup is just part of a much bigger application where  many teams work on. It had many reasons I cannot tell here, because of NDA, why we chose this architecture.

Comment: @Tseng how can we achieve similar thing with Electron + Angular ? Can we listen with a global hook in Electron + Angular ?

Comment: @Niklas have you find any solution ? if you can you please share here.. thanks in advance ..