# ASP.net c# trying to run an executable on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, executable

I have this method which generates a license by running an exe program on our server:

```
/// <summary>
/// Generate a new license
/// </summary>
public static void GenerateLicense(string Name, string EmailAddress, Licensing.Types.LicenseType Type, Licensing.Types.ProductTypes Product)
{
    string Params = "\"" + Licensing.Types.LicenseTypeToString(Type) + "\" \""
        + Licensing.Types.ProductTypeToString(Product)
        + "\" \"" + Name + "\" \""
        + EmailAddress + "\"";

    // Start license executable and pass in all the params
    Process.Start(Settings.LicenseExecutableLocation, Params);

}
```

It's not throwing any errors, and it's not apparently running the program (it should be making some files on the server).  The location of the executable (Settings.LicenseExecutableLocation) is `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\licensegen.exe` which is correct, and the paramaters are also correct (I've printed them out).

I'm running IIS7, it's not throwing *any* errors at all, do I need to change something in IIS7?

Comment: Is the file not running at all (verified by checking the process explorer), or just not outputting the files?

Comment: Are you using Server 2008?  Have you tried running the process from the command line?

Comment: Who's calling this method? Each web request (probably not) or the startup code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.Diagnostics.Process.Start not work fom an IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679561/system-diagnostics-process-start-not-work-fom-an-iis)

Comment: @Kyle I keep the task manager up and it's not popping up, it's a very quick process so I might miss it, not sure how to see what it's doing really

Comment: @John I'm on windows 7 but the live server is 2008 which I haven't tried it on yet

Comment: @Tom I think Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) will track if a process opens then closes quickly, so you can see if its actually getting started or not.

Comment: @Kyle the question you linked I tried to go through it but the instructions don't work for me, that's for XP and below, I'm on Windows 7 and there is no `IIS Admin Service.`

Comment: Hmm... try modifying execute permissions to allow scripts and executables. I also named a few other suggestions below as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're not getting an exception when launching the process, you need to find out what it is actually doing. I would change your last line to

```
var pLicenseGenerator =  Process.Start(Settings.LicenseExecutableLocation, Params);
```

And then investigate the properties of the pLicenseGenerator object in a debug session after waiting a few seconds for the process to do its thing. This object will be of the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process_members%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) class and I would pay special attention to the `.ExitCode` property. In a well-designed console application, this will be set to a non-zero value if the program encountered an error (like the old DOS %ERRORLEVEL% variable.)

If `.ExitCode` doesn't help, I'd recommend dumping [.StandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to the web page or to a file for debugging.

When I've run into similar issues in the past, it's always been a problem with the way I formatted the process's input parameters. Sometimes if a parameter is a long file path, you need to pay special attention to the way you wrap it in double-quotes.

One simple step would be to spit out the exact path and parameters you are passing to `Process.Start()` and then see what happens when you run them yourself from the command line. If they work fine, then it is probably some sort of permission-related issue, as another poster speculated.

Answer (score 1):

You might be running into a permissions issue. Does the executable reside in the same directory as the web application? If not, you may need to modify permissions or look into using impersonation. If it does reside in the same directory, you should try using a relative path. You may also need to suppress the console dialog - I've experienced problems with that.

Hope this helps.