# Process.Startinfo to print PDF not working in Windows Server 2003 from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

I have the below code in ASP.NET C# and it work fine in local system + production machine when i tested in debug mode. but it doesn't work when i uploading to IIS.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath(filePath);
                startInfo.Verb = "print";
                startInfo.Arguments = "Printer Name";
                Process proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
                proc.Start();

                proc.WaitForExit(5000);
                if (proc.HasExited == false)
                {
                    proc.Kill();
                }
```

Things i tried.

1. Control panel > Admin Services > Services > IIS Admin Service > Log on Tab > check to interact with desktop. Reset IIS Admin and IIS.
2. Printer Properties > Security > Grand ASPNET, NETWORK SERVICE, EVERYONE to full access.
3. Tried to set another printer as Default Printer. Reinstall / Add Printer.

I tried all the above with no success. finally i tried below in my machine.config.

1. WINNT>Microsoft.NET>Framework>v2.52something>Config> machine.config

I replaced this

> processModel autoConfig="true"

with this

> processModel userName="SYSTEM" password="AutoGenerate"

and i am getting this message

> "Before you can perform print-related tasks you need to install a
>   printer"

i am using acrobat 7 and i can print the test page from printer itself and from acrobat software.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Verb if acrobat is installed on you machine. and pass printer name as arguments

```
var fileName = @"c:\pdf\file.pdf";
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName);
            string verbToUse = "PrintTo";
            startInfo.Verb = verbToUse;
            startInfo.Arguments = "PrinterName";
            Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: you will have to install acrobat reader on the production machine.. Windows have to detect that .pdf extension has acrobat reader assocaited with it..

Comment: yes i have already installed it in production machine. actually i have already managed to print in production machine using old code that i posted in my question. help

Comment: try using the "print" verb instead of "PrintTo"

Comment: alright... try creating a sample console app from the example given in this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Hi thanks Shoaib, but as i stated above, it is working fine in debug mode. so even if i create a sample console app, it will also work in debug mode. i think it's something related with security issue in IIS. help!

Comment: can you check EventViewer for you server where site is hosted.. there must be some detail about what cause not to print

Comment: thanks Shoaib, all the event viewer logs are normal and nothing seems related to my printer problem. it's local printer and i tried both print and printto with no success.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be that IIS runs under a different user that has less permissions than a typical User. See [System.Diagnostics.Process.Start not work from an IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679561/system-diagnostics-process-start-not-work-fom-an-iis)

I fixed it on my server by changing the ProcessModel Identity to a user that has permissions. Probably a workaround and bad practice, but it worked. {Application Pool} -> Advanced Settings -> Identity -> Custom Account (Also toggle Load User Profile to true)