# exe file is unable to create txt file from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, file-permissions, iis-express

I have created an WebApi project in which I am calling a exe namely `Latlong2XY.exe` which takes input file and outputfile as paramreter. And returning me a .txt as output file. When I am executing the application from VS2012 IDE it is successfully creating the required txt file. However when I publish the same application in IIS and running it then it is not able to create the txt file.

**it appears IIS Express is creating the txt file while IIS is not.**

It appears to be some permission issue. But does not have any clue what to do.
My code is:

```
        int exitCode;
        // Prepare the process to run
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        // Enter in the command line arguments, everything you would enter after the executable name itself
        start.Arguments = @"D:\RFD\InputFile.txt D:\RFD\Results.txt";
        // Enter the executable to run, including the complete path
        start.FileName = @"D:\RFD\Latlong2XY.exe";
        // Do you want to show a console window?
        start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        start.CreateNoWindow = true;

        // Run the external process & wait for it to finish
        using (Process proc = Process.Start(start))
         {
            proc.WaitForExit();

            // Retrieve the app's exit code
            exitCode = proc.ExitCode;

        }
```

IIS settings are :

Windows Authentication: disabled; 
Forms Authentication: disabled; 
Anon auth: enabled;
.Net Impersonation: disabled.

i'm using ASP.NET v4.0 Application pool.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4679686/1293175

Comment: @sudhakar-tillapudi have a look on the above link also. It will also help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to give the application directory (where the hosted files are on the machine) elevated privileges. (Typically C:\inetpub\wwwroot\YourAppName)

Give the user 'IIS_USR' or something close to that name write access to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes., When you perform these kind of operations from `"Visual Studio IDE"` It will work because `IDE` has minimum permission to control your IO operations for (System.Diagnostics.Process.Start).

When you go to `Web application` hosting from IIS, unfortunately IIS doesn't have these permission settings in built. So you need to set permissions to perform `windows native operations`.

**Note :** By using this you are gonna provide your system(server) username and password as encrypted.

You can set windows authentication permission in the Web Config Using `Aspnet_setreg.exe`. Which will be available in internet with usage notes.

**Add the below line in your webconfig:**

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>

<identity impersonate ="true"  userName="registry:HKLM\SOFTWARE\YourAPPName\ASPNET_SETREG,userName" password="registry:HKLM\SOFTWARE\YOURAPPNAME\ASPNET_SETREG,password"/>
```

The similar problem i have faced during development of "windows service Re-Start from web". The Same permission issues i have resolved and got worked on this way.

This answer may not be perfect. But this is also one way to achieve the solution

Comment: dear @RJK thanks for your answer,i will try and let you know.