# Pass arguments from website to C# console application

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to get ideas, on how I can pass parameters from a website, to a C# console application. The website is built in .NET. The C# console application requires some arguments to be passed to it in order to trigger certain functions. Is it possible to pass in these arguments from a website?

Comment: Please specify where you "console application" is running (server or client or somewhere else altogether).

Comment: The console application can go GET the parameters from a web site (webapi, rest, json or some such) but security will prohibit you from calling a local console application from a web site.

Comment: Need more context so we know what you're trying to do...

Comment: Classical [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), You think *you can solve your problem with passing some parameters to Console app*, and ask a solution for this instead of asking your *real* problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few scenarios, and we don't know which is the case, so I will outline each one:

**Scenario 1)** If your console application is running on the server, you could start a process with `Process.Start()` (assuming you have your server configured in a manner where this will work, see [this SO question and first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679561/system-diagnostics-process-start-not-work-fom-an-iis)).

**Scenario 2)** If your console app is running on a client computer and you have a hostname or ip that points to the client, and firewalls do not prevent communications with the client, then you could open a port and communicate with it. This is tedious and probably not worth the time though; instead, I'd suggest (as @paqogomez commented) setting up a web api or something to *retrieve* the parameters. Because you already have the webserver configured, you shouldn't need to worry about additional firewall configuration, and you can retrieve the values with a simple webrequest or web service.

**Scenario 3)** If your console app is running on a client computer and you **do not** have a hostname or ip that points to the client, then you cannot send data to the client; however, you can still have the client retrieve the data as explained in Scenario 2.