# Need to open link in IE from FIREFOX

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

I have developed application in mvc 5 from where I need to open next web application from link which runs only in IE < 9 ;but my application runs in firefox and is NOT supported in IE < 9. So I managed to open the application from  Process.Start("IExplore.exe", http); which works fine in debug but while application is hosted it doesn't work. So I need a solution to open application from firefox in IE using backend c# code or javascript.

Comment: Try to fix bug, and make it work on IE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "iexplore.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "http:\\\\www.google.com";
p.Start();
```

This will open Internet Explorer, and immediately load the website passed in as an argument.

Also, the Process class is part of the System.Diagnostics namespace. Be sure to reference it at the top of your code file.

if you are using windows 8 or higher then you can use

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("IEXPLORE.EXE", MyURLHere)
```

Comment: I am using this in asp.net mvc 5 web application and it works fine in debug in vs 2013 but when I host it in iis it doesnot works at all. And I have hosted it in local system with full permission.

Comment: Please verify whether the application user has access to the system processess.

Comment: Yeah I have deployed in local system in iis and I think local system has full permission.

Comment: You can refer to the below post and i hope it might help you solve the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679561/system-diagnostics-process-start-not-work-fom-an-iis