# print pdf silently in c#

Tags: pdf-generation, adobe, acrobat

I am trying to print pdf silently using adobe reader.
I have taken the example from the following location:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/598424/How-to-Silently-Print-PDFs-using-Adobe-Reader-and

I am able to work as desired with the above example code in my localhost.

But when I deploy my application on the server,I am unable to print the PDFs.

In my localhost on button click event,I am creating the PDFs and saving it to one location and printing the same.While printing adobe window opens and prints the PDFs and exits automatically.

The same doesn't work in my server.I am able to create and save PDFs,but adobe is not opening and printing my file.I am not even getting any exception/error.It simply doesn't show up adobe window.

Did anyone face the same issue.
Any help in this regard.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

If you are running on a Web Server using ASP.NET or in general IIS  the new process executes on the Web server with restricted permissions. I point you out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679561/system-diagnostics-process-start-not-work-fom-an-iis) that could explain the cause of your problem.

---

However the code you are using doesn't print any error message. You probably don't have access to the directory where the AcroRd32.exe is located.

Let's take this function from the article you posted:

```
public static Boolean PrintPDFs(string pdfFileName)
{
     try
       {
                Process proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                proc.StartInfo.Verb = "print";

                //Define location of adobe reader/command line
                //switches to launch adobe in "print" mode
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = 
                  @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"/p /h {0}", pdfFileName);
                proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

                proc.Start();
                proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                if (proc.HasExited == false)
                {
                    proc.WaitForExit(10000);
                }

                proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                proc.Close();
                KillAdobe("AcroRd32");
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
  }
```

*PrintPDFs* uses a process, which is called by the .NET framework using the **Process** class. In the *StartInfo* option you look carefully two options are set:

```
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

The first redirect the standard output stream to your application while the second hides the cmd window. The former is handy to use process without showing to the user a command window but the latter hide the console window. The main drawback is, if you're debugging, that you probably won't see error coming through.

One way to debug it would require to add the following to lines:

```
 proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 proc.Start();    

 Console.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

Another property you can look at is [ExitCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode(v=vs.110).aspx). If that is greather than zero means that your process exit with some error.

hope it helps.

Comment: I am able to print when I use this dll from a console app.When i consume the same dll from Web app,it doesn't work

Comment: you're problem is executing the process with limited permission. I edited the asnwer

Answer (score -1):

A silent printing can be achieved with an Acroread command line parameters or with a PDF JavaScript event handler (of course, if your PDF producer tool has a possibility to define/inject PDF's OpenAction handler).

See http://pd4ml.com/cookbook/pdf_automated_printing.htm

With the JavaScript approach you are not bound to a printer driver, network name or IP address. On the other hand, JavaScript in Acroread can be disabled, for example, by a corporate security policy.

Answer (score -1):

use this with [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/index.html) that is GNU:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        var FileName = @"C:\ResultadoFormulario_CClastMovements.pdf";
        var pathPrinter = @"\\Server\namePrinter";
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        var pathGsw = @"path gswin64c here\";
        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        string strCmdText = $"{pathGsw}gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dNoCancel -dPDFFitPage -sOutputFile=\"%printer%{direccionImpresora}\" \"{FileName}\"";
        Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```