# Open a WPF Application from Web API that is hosted on IIS

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-web-api

I know there are similar questions related to my question in stackoverflow and you may consider this question as a repeated question, but none of the related questions helped me to solve this problem.

I have a WPF application on my client and also a ASP.NET Web API application hosted on the IIS in the same system.

I need to start the WPF Application from the hosted Web API Methods.

The application can be closed from the API using Process.Close.

When I try to start the application using Process.Start(processstartinfo), it is showing in the taskbar (when I check the show process from all users), but not showing in the Desktop UI.

Please help me guys to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your IIS worker process don't have enough permission to run in the user's desktop. 
You need to give enough permission to your worker process.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679561/system-diagnostics-process-start-not-work-fom-an-iis) link for more detail on how to do it.

Comment: i already tried this by giving full permission to the worker process account and also giving Local system account for the worker process.

Comment: Did you make sure that your Web API is running in the same application pool that you gave Local System permission to?

Comment: When you check the 'Show Process from all user', what account it shows running under?

Comment: It's an administrator account for that system and that process is running under this account.

Comment: @ANewGuyInTown - it's not that you "don't have enough permissions" per se; it's that the process is being started by the same one that runs the IIS App Pool for the API WebApp. Might be considered me being pedantic, but I find this answer is technically inaccurate