# System.Diagnostics.Process not working after publishing MVC App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, process, iis-7.5, system.diagnostics

I need to start an exe on a click, so I have written below code and it is working when I run it with visual studio. However when we publish the app it fails to work on client.

```
  public ActionResult ShowModuleApp(string modulePath)
        {
            var returnUrl = Request.UrlReferrer;
            try
            {
                Process process = Process.Start(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + @"Uploads\" + modulePath);
                int exeId = process.Id;
                Process tempProc = Process.GetProcessById(exeId);
                process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                GeneralFunctions.AddTraceLog(Convert.ToString(exeId));

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                GeneralFunctions.AddTraceLog(ex.Message);
                return Redirect(returnUrl.AbsoluteUri);
            }

            return Redirect(returnUrl.AbsoluteUri);

        }
```

I have also followed the below instructions.

To configure this, follow this steps.
a. Open Control Panel and follow these steps: For Windows NT: click Services. For Windows 2000, Windows XP, and .NET Server: click Administrative Tools, and then click Services.

b. Double-click IIS Admin Service.

c. On the Log On tab, select the Allow Service to Interact with Desktop check 
box. Remember to run IIS Admin Service as a local system.

d. Stop and restart the IIS Admin Service.

But its not working either, I can see the Process Id logged in trace logs. Is it running in the background and not coming in front as I can see no exception traced.

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679561/system-diagnostics-process-start-not-work-from-an-iis

Comment: @JohnB I have tried the accepted and possible solution mentioned in the post you are suggesting. but It is not working.

Comment: Does the process exit? What exit code does it have? check the windows events logs, the process might have crashed.

Comment: @Alex Yes. The process exists.