# System.Diagnostics.Process.Start not work with IIS, but on ASP.NET Development Server 10

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I have an aspnetcore application version 5.0 that calls executables in its process when I'm in development environment, but when this application is installed on IIS, the process doesn't work.

I use the version of IIS installed on the "Windows Server 2016" server is: 10

Comment: There are tons of differences you cannot neglect, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: User's in the client, did some operation then your server will start an application. Do you think this kind of operation should be allowed? By the way, remote server send some requests to the client, then your website will start an application installed in the user's computer. Should be allowed? So I think your issue should be an expected behavior when the permissions is limited.

Comment: @TinyWang, How to enable permission?

Comment: set application pool permission to "localsystem" may help. [This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-authentication-authorization/understanding-identities#application-pool-identities) and follow the steps from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59749448).

Comment: you may try it, I'm not sure if it worked, and I also don't recommend to start an application by this if it's not necessary.