# Open process as another user

Tags: c#, process, usersession

I'm writing a C# program that runs on a remote windows embedded device. it is running in admin mode.

From this program I try to open an exe, but by default, this exe is opened in the same admin session.

How can I open it as another user?

I already tried different things googled here and there, especially : [Starting a process with credentials from a Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677874/starting-a-process-with-credentials-from-a-windows-service/30687230#30687230).

But it still opens in the admin session.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Just for clarification, is the app that is trying to launch the process a service ? Or is it a more classical desktop (GUI / CLI) app ? Because on windows, that WILL have an impact.

Comment: Sounds like you need impersonation

Comment: App is a CLI, but might be a service as well, depend if it's better as you seem to mention that there might be a difference.