# Code isn't executing in windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to start a process from windows service into currently logged in user’s session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278373/how-to-start-a-process-from-windows-service-into-currently-logged-in-users-sess)
>   [c# windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595615/c-sharp-windows-service)

I have this code in the `OnStart` Method of the windows service.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe");
```

I am successfully able to start the windows service. However once the service has successfully started it doesn't open the notepad.

This is a strange problem and as i am new to windows services, help is required.

Comment: Perhaps this is a security issue?

Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456155/system-diagnostics-process-start-cannot-start-process-when-called-from-windows

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5595615/11683

Comment: @GSerg Thanks for the second link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows services don't execute in the same context as the desktop.

Hence you won't see the application running in explorer like you would if you launched it normally.

Comment: @WinCoder i'm tempted to ask why you'd want a windows service to start notepad (or any other app) You may be better of using regular exe and setting task scheduler to run it at intervals.

Comment: just started learning windows service and wanted to do different things with it, didn't knew that this simple task was hard as hell.

Comment: @WinCoder It's not really difficult, just impossible .. by design.

Comment: hmmm well i guess can't do it then....and i suppose i won't be able to disply a textbox either would i ?

Comment: Write an event to the event log if you want to know if your service started.