# Start a process as LocalSystem using ProcessStartInfo

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to start a process as the LocalSystem account using this code

```
    ProcessStartInfo _startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(commandName);
_startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
_startInfo.UserName = @"NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM";
_startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
_startInfo.Arguments = argument;
_startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

using (Process _p = Process.Start(_startInfo)) {
  _retVal = _p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
  _p.WaitForExit();
}
```

But I am getting always the same error message saying "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password". The user calling the function is a local admin and should be able to start a process with local system privilege. I also tried different combination but no luck.

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can do it so simply.

The underlying API that Process.Start() calls accepts a username and password, but since the SYSTEM user isn't a regular user and doesn't have a password I don't believe you can use it with this API.

You would have to use something like [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) (which you can, of course, call from `Process.Start()`).

Comment: This is the version I will use :-)  
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had some difficulties with this a while back. In the end managed it. What you're probably missing is some permission or other. See my [previous question/answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362419/using-process-start-to-start-a-process-as-a-different-user-from-within-a-window)