# Spawn process in the context of different user

Tags: c#, windows, service, elevated-privileges

At the moment I have a service which will execute from time to time a `.exe` file. As the service is run as the `SYSTEM` user, these subprocesses will also be executed by `SYSTEM`. Due to security reasons I would like these processes to be executed in the context of a different user without administrative priviliges. Is there a way to do this without having to store the username and the password of this user somehow? If not: How can I save these credentials in a secure way?

I am using `C#` for the service, but I think that this questions can also be answered in general.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362419/using-process-start-to-start-a-process-as-a-different-user-from-within-a-windo answer your question?

Comment: are you need context of concrete user or simply execute with restricted token ?

Comment: @Brad I have seen this answer, but do not know how to store the user's credentials in a secure way. @RbMm; I want to execute it with restricted privileges of this specific user.